# Finding individual timespans between two columns of data in datetime format, possibly using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime

I am new to Python and coding in general and I have an issue with programming a for loop, as suggested by an instructor, to find the time elapsed between the shutdown and restart times for a powerplant.

I managed to isolate the columns I was interested in by forming a dataframe:

```
oilSubData4 = pd.DataFrame(oilData[['Shutdown Date/Time', 'Restart Date/Time']])
```

I also managed to convert the columns into datetime format and removed the NaT rows:

```
oilSubData4['Shutdown Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(oilSubData4['Shutdown Date/Time'])
oilSubData4['Restart Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(oilSubData4['Restart Date/Time'])
oilShutdownTime = oilSubData4.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
```

It all culminated to form this 
[image of the data I wish to find the individual timespans of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3usBn.png)

It's at this point that I struggled to find a way to find the time difference between each restart time/date and shutdown time/date for each row of data. I am not experienced with for loops and I am unsure of how to begin.

My attempt is as follows:

```
for x in oilShutdownTime:
oilShutdownTime['time_diff'][x+1] = oilShutdownTime['Restart Date/Time'][x+1] - oilShutdownTime['Restart Date/Time'][x]
```

and the following error shows:

> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         1 for x in oilShutdownTime:
>   ----> 2     oilShutdownTime['time_diff'][x+1] = oilShutdownTime['Restart Date/Time'][x+1] - oilShutdownTime['Restart Date/Time'][x]
>
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Please advise on how to fix this if possible. I am aware that my code might be wholly inaccurate so any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop confuses me. I am not sure what you where trying to do.

Let's take the first row from your example:

```
"Shutdown Date/Time","Restart Date/Time"
2010-01-08 23:41:00,2010-01-13 09:17:00
```

Do you want the result for this row to be `4 days 09:36:00`? This is how I understand your question. In that case, try the following:

```py
>>> oilShutdownTime['Restart Date/Time'] - oilShutdownTime['Shutdown Date/Time']

0   4 days 09:36:00
1   0 days 01:00:00
2   0 days 00:00:40
3   0 days 12:10:00
4   1 days 10:03:15
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Note: Only the first row is real data, I did not type in all dates from your image..

There might be no need for a loop at this point. Pandas can handle column-wise calculations way more efficiently internally than you could with a for-loop on your own.